# Salto de linea en FPDF PHP

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de insertar un salto de linea dentro del "Titulo" de la celda

```
$pdf->Cell(15,9, utf8_decode("Cargo\n en dependencia"),1, 0 , 'L' );
```

Pero por alguna razón no funciona.
Tendran alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aporto con una manera diferente de realizarlo.
Entiendo que el problema es que no hace el **salto de línea** pero cuando lo hace,  coloca el titulo justo **abajo** del que ya coloco. Quedando encimados y no uno alado del otro.

##### Salto de línea en mas de un titulo

Multicell utiliza los siguientes parámetros:

```
MultiCell(float w, float h, string txt [, mixed border [, string align [, boolean fill]]])
```

##### Parámetros

**w**: Ancho de celdas. Si 0, estos se extienden hasta l margen derecho de la página.
**h**: Alto de las celdas.
**txt**: Cadena para imprimir.
**border**:
Indica si los bordes deben ser dibujados al rededor del bloque la celda. El valor puede ser un número:
0: no borde
1: marco
o una cadena conteniendo algún o todos los siguientes caracteres (en cualquier orden):
L: izquierda
T: superior
R: derecha
B: inferior
Valor por defecto: 0.
**align**: Establece la alineación de texto. Los posibles valores son:
L: alineación a la izquierda
C: centrado
R: alineación a la derecha
J: justificación (valor por defecto)
**fill**: Indica si el fondo de la celda debe ser dibujado (**true**) o transparente (**false**). Valor por defecto: false.

Necesitamos la **librería FPDP** que puede descargarse del sitio oficial: http://fpdf.org/es/download.php

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Multicell(120, 5, utf8_decode("Cargo1\nen dependencia"), 0, 'l', false);
$x = $pdf->GetX();
$y = $pdf->GetY();
$pdf->SetXY($x+100, $y-10);
$pdf->Multicell(120, 5, utf8_decode("Cargo2\nen dependencia"), 0, 'l', false);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

##### Explicando el código:

`$pdf->Multicell(120, 5, utf8_decode("Cargo1\nen dependencia"), 0, 'l', false);` Carga el **primer Multicell** y la **posición siguiente** para continuar escribiendo será justo debajo a la izquierda para comenzar una nueva línea.

##### Posición de titulo siguiente:

`$x = $pdf->GetX();` y `$y = $pdf->GetY();` nos da la posición de abscisas y ordenadas respectivamente.

Ahora `$x` y `$y` tiene los datos de posición que nos servirá para darle una nueva posición.

`$pdf->SetXY($x+100, $y-10);` seteamos ahora la posición a donde queramos. En este caso le sumamos +100 a la abscisa y le restamos 10 a la ordenada para que quede mas arriba. (Los valores que le asignamos a **SetXY** serán los que posicionen el nuevo titulo y dependerán de que tamaño le damos a la tipografía, espacio ocupado o **personalizaciones** que queramos hacer.)

La **imagen** siguiente muestra **el resultado**. (Los dos títulos están a la misma altura.)

[image: Vista previa PDF con dos títulos en la misma línea]

Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 4):

Como fue descrito [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861809/inserting-line-breaks-into-pdf), debes usar `Multicell`

```
$pdf->Multicell(0,2,"This is a multi-line text string\nNew line\nNew line");
```

Asegúrate de usar dobles comillas y no comillas simples.

[Documentación](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm).

Comment: Funciona, pero hace una celda para solo una fila, es decir,es como si hiciera un salto de linea para la celda también y no puedo ponerla al lado de otra multicell o celda, no se si me expliqué

Comment: @karlDomínguez No, no te explicas, lo que ha escrito Jacob responde concretamente a tu pregunta. Afina más tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Mira este ejemplo que tengo aqui

```
$pdf->Multicell(0, 5, utf8_decode("Con lo que terminó la presente acta administrativa, firmando los que en ella intervinieron y quisieron hacerlo, el día 12 de octubre del 2020 a las 9:20 a.m. aproximadamente.\n\n"));
```

Con "\n" Hago los saltos en linea

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).